Prevent screenshot on react-native-modal android
I am trying to prevent screenshot on react-native-modal but not able to do it. I have use the secured flags provided by android
fun preventScreenshot() {
        val activity = currentActivity
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
        activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
        }
    }

It seems like this is a known issue, is there any workaround for this issue?
